# Getting the number of digits in hex number without removing the leading zeros in python

Tags: python, hex, digits

I want to calculate the number of digits in hex number in python for example:

```py
num = 0X0101
num1 = 0X00001
print(len(format(num, "04x")))
```

the problem is the number of digits and the leading zeros are variable so this line will not work.

```py
print(len(format(num, "04x")))
```

Note that `num` and `num1` are just an example and could have a different values.

I want to calculate the number of digits in hex number without removing the leading zeros.

Comment: `num1 = 0X00001` has exactly the same result as `num1 = 1`. Any information about leading zeroes or if the number was written in hex or decimal notation isn't stored in `num1`.

Comment: If you want leading zeroes to be preserved, you have to use a string, not a number.

Comment: What is the actual programming context for this? What *specific* problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: This appears to be a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). There is no such thing as "leading zeros" in the numerical representation. As Barmar points out if the leading zeros are significant (which they normally are not) then you have to use a string repsentation -- not a numerical representation.